# Prove that you can design any digital circuit with only NAND gate or only NOR gate

Tags: data-structures

I have read that NAND gate and NOR gate are called universal gates... but i cannot find a rigorous proof that any circuit can be designed by these two gates only.

Comment: (What do you know/think to be a *universal set of gates*, how about $\land, \lor, \neg$? Is there any gate in any given such set that you can't build from NAND? From NOR?)

Comment: Are you familiar with CNF/DNF?